# Injecting arrays with Unity

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

My goal is to constructor inject an array of objects implementing an interface.

The following is the way I currently have it.

```
Container

        .RegisterInstance<Company>(ParseCompany(args[1])

        .RegisterInstance<eTargets>(ParseTargets(args[2]))

        .RegisterInstance<ILoader[]>(new ILoader[] {
            Container.Resolve<CustomerLoader>(),
            Container.Resolve<PaymentLoader(),
            Container.Resolve<InvoiceLoader() 
        });
```

Is it typical to call Resolve in container configuration this way or is there a more standard way to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Unity **natively understands arrays**, so there's no reason to make it so complicated. Just register the `ILoaders` you want to include and resolve the object graphs normally. **Auto-wiring** will take care of the rest:

```
container.RegisterType<ILoader, FooLoader>("foo");
container.RegisterType<ILoader, BarLoader>("bar");
container.RegisterType<ILoader, BazLoader>("baz");

var c = container.Resolve<MyConsumer>();
```

assuming that the `MyConsumer` constructor is defined like this:

```
public MyConsumer(ILoader[] loaders)
```

However, you should be aware that (for some unfathomable reason) Unity only includes *named* components in this way. The *default* component:

```
container.RegisterType<ILoader, Loader>();
```

will *not* be included in the array, since it has no name.

Comment: Not exactly unfathomable: the reason is that, if you need more than one entry for the same type, then you must add a name otherwise Unity will think you're actually overriding the previous entry (which is forbidden).

Comment: @BrunoBrant 'unfathomable' because no other DI Container works like that. See e.g. [my book](http://amzn.to/12p90MG) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a slightly more complicated scenario where different arrays of values have to be used in different places, then you can use ResolvedArrayParameter, e.g.

```
container.RegisterType<ILoader, FooLoader>("foo");
container.RegisterType<ILoader, BarLoader>("bar");
container.RegisterType<ILoader, BazLoader>("baz");
container.RegisterType<ILoader, BooLoader>("boo");

container.RegisterType<IConsumer, MyConsumer>("c1",
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedArrayParameter<ILoader>(
            new ResolvedParameter<ILoader>("foo"),
            new ResolvedParameter<ILoader>("bar"))));

container.RegisterType<IConsumer, MyConsumer>("c2",
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedArrayParameter<ILoader>(
            new ResolvedParameter<ILoader>("baz"),
            new ResolvedParameter<ILoader>("boo"))));

var c1 = container.Resolve<MyConsumer>("c1");
var c1 = container.Resolve<MyConsumer>("c2");
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `Resolve` during "configuration time" is acceptable and often useful, and it's perfectly valid for arrays or enumerables.

You could also have done the above by registering the `ILoader[]` type and registering each of the specific `ILoader` types using the `RegisterType` overload that takes a name.

Then, wherever `ILoader[]` is required (e.g. needs to be injected), all of the above will resolve for you after configuration time. Of course, if you need multiple/different `ILoader[]` it would devolve back to needing to use `Resolve` during configuration time.