# Unity Injection of Arrays - What is the Order?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I see [Unity can indeed inject an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8186925/284758).  Fantastic.

What I'd like to know is what Unity guarantees, if anything, about the order of the array objects that are injected?  Is it:

- The order in which the array elements were registered?
- The alphabetical order of the concrete registered type names?
- The alphabetical order of registered *named* component?
- ...or is it an undefined order?

Finally, I'd like to know if it is still true that a default (unnamed) component still cannot be injected as an array element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer

The order the elements were registered.
Unnamed types will be filtered out of the list.

### Long Answer

I do not see anywhere in the documentation that says one way or the other.  This tells me that there is no "guarantee" from a design standpoint.  Because there is no guarantee from a design standpoint, I would assume it is subject to change.

Going by the code...

All injection methods behind the scenes call `IUnityContainer.ResolveAll(Type, params ResolverOverride[])`, so all injection methods will result in the same order.  (i.e. constructor injection, parameter injection, direct call to ResolveAll)

`ResolveAll` does the work.  The order is defined by the order the elements were registered within a single container.

Also consider the case of parent/child containers.  The order will be recursively the root container first, then each child down to the requested container.  Also, if there is a duplicate registered name between two containers, the top most parent registration will be the only one resolved.

This is my own analysis of the [source](https://unity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Unity/Unity/Src/UnityContainer.cs).