# Resolving and registering an array of items in Unity

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I want to inject a collection of configuration items into constructors via Unity.

Here's an example illustrating what I've currently got, which is failing to insert the array I was hoping for into my constructor:

```cs
class ArgumentType
{
    public ArgumentType(string p1) { _p1 = p1; }
    private string _p1;
    public string P1 { get { return _p1; } }
}

class ConsumingType : IConsumingType /* interface omitted here */
{
    public ConsumingType( ArgumentType[] myArguments )
    {
       ...
    }
}

class Application
{
    private UnityContainer _container;
    public static void Main()
    { 
        _container = new UnityContainer()
        _container.RegisterType<ArgumentType[]>( new InjectionFactory(c => {
            return new ArgumentType[] {
                new ArgumentType("Foo"),
                new ArgumentType("Bar"),
                new ArgumentType("Baz") }; ) );
        _container.RegisterType<IConsumingType, ConsumingType>();

        var myUsefulThing = _container.Resolve<IConsumingType>();
        /* Do useful stuff */
    }
}
```

All the answers I'm finding for search terms like "Injecting array of objects using Unity" find examples where Unity returns an array of *different implementations of an interface*,  e.g. [Injecting arrays with Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186017/injecting-arrays-with-unity)

I'm aware there's loads of examples at the MSDN site (e.g. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660882(v=pandp.20).aspx#config_array_runtime ) but I'm not finding anything that really covers my use case. I also want to do this in code only (not in `app.config`).

An obvious workaround if this can't work is to create a type to hold my array -- this would be an easy enough solution, but I'm sure this should be possible with `InjectionFactory` or `InjectionConstructor`, or one of their siblings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could register the ArgumentTypes directly in Unity and not by registering and array with the instances. But you need to use a name for each ArgumentType.

When resolving your ConsumingType unity is smart enough to inject all registered ArgumentTypes as an array.

```
_container.RegisterInstance<ArgumentType>("Foo", new ArgumentType("Foo"));
_container.RegisterInstance<ArgumentType>("Bar", new ArgumentType("Bar"));
_container.RegisterInstance<ArgumentType>("Baz", new ArgumentType("Baz"));
_container.RegisterType<IConsumingType, ConsumingType>();

var myUsefulThing = _container.Resolve<IConsumingType>();
```

Comment: Ok, this has merit. But the compiler can't convert `ArgumentType` to the `InjectionMember` parameter needed on that overload of `RegisterInstance`.  Does the ArgumentType need to be wrapped in `InjectionConstructor` or similar?

Comment: In fact that's exactly the thing.

`_container.RegisterInstance<ArgumentType>("Foo", new InjectionConstructor("Foo"));`

If it works on my real life application code, you get the green tick :)

Comment: @CJBrew RegisterInstance has no need for InjectionMember cause you register instances. I think you mix that with RegisterType. But you could also use RegisterType<ArgumentType>("Foo", new InjectionConstructor("Foo"));

Comment: I've just realised you did "RegisterInstance"  not "RegisterType". Brilliant, thank you