# Injecting an array using Unity

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, strategy-pattern

I am using the Strategy Pattern, and injecting the dependencies using Unity.

I have a strategy interface and implementation:

```
 public interface IStrategy

 public class Strategy: IStrategy
    {
        private readonly IFactory[] factories;
        public Strategy(IFactory[] factories)
        {
            this.factories = factories ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("factories");
        }
    }
```

And some factories, interface and implementation:

```
public interface IFactory

public class Factory: IFactory
```

I am trying to inject the dependencies using Unity.

I have carefully read a topic that describes a situation close to this one ([Injecting arrays with Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186017/injecting-arrays-with-unity)), and implemented the solution described:

```
container.RegisterType<IFactory,Factory>("FactoryA");

container.RegisterType<IStrategy, Strategy>();

container.Resolve<Strategy>();
```

However, during the composition, the `factories[]` array passed to the `Strategy` constructor is always an empty array.

I thought I has well understood how this worked, as the question linked has a detailled answer, but I am obviously mistaken.

Could you help shed some light on this?